# Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 while building Image for Docket in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am learning this course of springboot by Dan Vega, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgX5lgv4uVM. I am getting an error I can't seem to get arround.

When I try to mvn spring-boot:build-image in maven to create an Image for Docker I am geting this error "Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51"

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.1:build-image (default-cli) @ content-calendar ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/content-calendar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:dd98964477407e67eb6620450c4f4a5d2236f8fdc8e6569ce3778318aa4b7e64'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:base-cnb' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:41443690a2dc36118112db2c4790dc2bc8189926dae9ff91992b78675d0cac39'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.16.1
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-b6484801b9ac.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Image with name "docker.io/library/content-calendar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 26 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.6.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 10.1.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.28.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.6.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.5.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.23.0
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.6.1
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.1.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              17                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 18 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.
[INFO]     [creator]        : Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request 
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from 
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

I am passing all the steps of maven build image process before actually building image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2eRI.png)

[INFO]     [creator]     Image with name "docker.io/library/content-calendar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found is the line where the issue is. I am fairly new to all SpringBoot, Maven and Docker. And I am using the exact code provide by Dan in the video crash course from https://github.com/danvega/content-calendar (which is working with the instructor).

To sucessfully build an Image from mvn spring-boot:build-image for the Docker

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error here is about

```
Using Java version 18 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
No valid JRE available
```

which is to be expected, since `Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.1.0` does not provide JDK or JRE version 18 (it just supports [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) JVM releases + the latest, which is `20` as of now; so no `18`)

Version `18` was detected from the `MANIFEST.MF` of the jar you're trying to build an OCI image from; which itself was set from the JVM you used to build your application.

I suggest you either use a JDK version `17` or `20` on your machine; a convenient way to switch between JDKs is using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/)

Hope that helps!