# Spring Boot - Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 - Maven Build Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a problem to build all modules in my Spring Boot App. Its name is food-ordering-system with different modules.

When I run this command `mvn clean install` under main folder named food-ordering-system as shown below

```
food-ordering-system> mvn clean install
```

I got this issue shown below

```
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Image with name "com.food.ordering.system/order.service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 26 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.6.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 10.1.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.28.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.6.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.5.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.23.0
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.6.1
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.1.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              17                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attac
hed
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 19 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.
[INFO]     [creator]        : Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for food-ordering-system 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] food-ordering-system ............................... SUCCESS [  0.663 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.083 s]
[INFO] common-domain ...................................... SUCCESS [  6.900 s]
[INFO] order-service ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.116 s]
[INFO] order-domain ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.085 s]
[INFO] order-domain-core .................................. SUCCESS [  3.181 s]
[INFO] order-application-service .......................... SUCCESS [ 17.563 s]
[INFO] common-application ................................. SUCCESS [  3.449 s]
[INFO] order-application .................................. SUCCESS [  2.688 s]
[INFO] common-dataaccess .................................. SUCCESS [  3.188 s]
[INFO] order-dataaccess ................................... SUCCESS [  4.135 s]
[INFO] infrastructure ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.105 s]
[INFO] kafka .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.080 s]
[INFO] kafka-model ........................................ SUCCESS [  7.408 s]
[INFO] kafka-config-data .................................. SUCCESS [  3.269 s]
[INFO] kafka-producer ..................................... SUCCESS [  3.667 s]
[INFO] kafka-consumer ..................................... SUCCESS [  2.176 s]
[INFO] order-messaging .................................... SUCCESS [  3.215 s]
[INFO] order-container .................................... FAILURE [ 20.277 s]
[INFO] customer-service ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-service .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-domain ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-domain-core ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-application-service ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-dataaccess ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-messaging .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-container .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-21T18:40:05+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.5:build-image (default) on project order-container: Execution default of goal org.springframework.b
oot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.5:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the code snippet shown below

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>${project.groupId}/payment.service:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here is the repo : [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bUuXYL369X-XNwcZrBGUO_lZIPEDtDPy/view?usp=share_link)

How can I fix it?

Comment: This related question could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76047772/292352

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 while building Image for Docket in Springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047772/builder-lifecycle-creator-failed-with-status-code-51-while-building-image-for)